# Prevent IDM from downloading videos from a website

Tags: html, web

A friend of mine has a website and you can watch videos on it but if you have IDM you can download the video. Is it possible to play the videos and not let IDM download them from there? Any answer that even slightly helps is appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802862/how-to-stop-idm-from-grabbing-video-audio

Comment: This question has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is: STREAM THE VIDEO IN SEPARATED ENCRYPTED PARTS.

There are video hosting services such as vzaar that have this functionality. As far as I know, that will make it really hard to download directly. At least for 95% of the people.

But of course, if the video plays on the screen people can just use a screen recorder and some simple software to record sound from the audio output (but he/she will have to play the ENTIRE thing to save it, totally inconvenient).